# How to prevent missing hyphens when printing PDF from evince?

Tags: debian, pdf, printing, evince

I encounter the same problem as explained in [this blog](https://medium.com/@lauradietz100/missing-dashes-and-hyphens-when-printing-pdf-d19bc4d2787c), when I print a pdf from evince hyphens are not printed. when I print a pdf from Okular, hyphens are printed. For example the hyphen that appears at the end of the first line in this text:

[image]

Both evince and Okular are [recommended pdf viewers on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PDF), but I would prefer to use evince since it's the default for Gnome and it's already integrated with some other software I use.

Here are the Latex and Lyx files that can be used to generate the problematic pdf: [hyphen.lyx](https://gist.github.com/paul4forest/642e1ddfb03fa420ea32)

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of evince and cups?

Comment: @harrymc I'm using [evince 3.14.1-2](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/evince) and [cups 1.7.5-11+deb8u1](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/cups) those are both the latest versions in Debian Stable.

Comment: The problematic hyphen is usually a soft-hyphen, which is a different character than the hyphen. If the font is not embedded within the pdf, evince will match it against some font in system. Evince might be using the wrong font match when printing. Try not to encode the file in UTF8, if possible, so not to generate that character.

Comment: Thanks but since I also write in French, and exchange data with Scandinavian people, I tend to use UTF8.

Comment: Bonjour. You should also check that you have the latest printer driver. If the file prints correctly on another computer in your household, you could try to print via the internal network. Otherwise: (1) Accented characters are also to be found in  [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), but I believe not the soft-hyphen. (2) As last resort you will need to modify the font-mapping rules in your system, however I don't have any idea why evince uses different fonts for the printer. See [this thread](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=282151) for an example of sleuthing.

Comment: Something else that might help is when generating the pdf, to ensure that the fonts are embedded. See the [Lyx PDF FAQ](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF#embedFonts).

Answer (score 1):

This bug has apparently [been fixed](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94615). However, as far as I can tell, the fix has not been backported.